# Projective dimension of group ring

Tags: rt.representation-theory, arithmetic-geometry, group-cohomology, noncommutative-algebra, local-systems

Assume that  $G$ is a group and $R$ is a p.i.d. What can we say about the projective dimension of $R[G]$? For example can we say that this dimension is at most $1$ for reductive groups? (I think if  $R$ is a field then this is true.) What about an arithmetic subgroup of a reductive group?

Comment: What do you mean by the group ring of a reductive group?

Comment: RG is projective and so has projective dimension 0.  Projective dimension is for modules not rings. Do you mean global dimension or cohomological dimension (projective dimension of the trivial module 1)?

Comment: Yes I mean global dimension

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე it means the formal sum of elements of G with coefficient in R.( by a reductive group I mean the points over $\mathbb{C}$ not the group scheme)

Comment: In case this is useful, [Dicks's theorem on hereditary group rings](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/theorems/theorem/116/) characterizes when $R[G]$ has global dimension $\leq 1$.  (Dicks, Warren. "Hereditary group rings." Journal of the London Mathematical Society 2.1 (1979): 27-38.)

Comment: @ali If you mean "global dimension" and not "projective dimension" you should edit your problem statement asap to clear things up.

Answer (score 1):

There are the inequalities
$$\max\{\textrm{gl.dim}(R),\textrm{cohom.dim}_R(G)\}\le\textrm{gl.dim}(RG)\le\textrm{gl.dim}(R)+\textrm{cohom.dim}_R(G).$$
The right hand inequality is often realized (as an equality).
In general I think it would be hard to compute when the right hand inequality is realized.

Comment: The global dimension always is an upper bound on the cohomological dimension and the global dimension of a pid is \leq 1

Comment: Anyway it won't be 1 for a non virtually free group.

Comment: I am pretty sure $\mathrm{cohom.dim}_{\mathbb Z}(\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb C))$ is infinity: cohomologies of $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb C)$ contain lots of stuff coming from algebraic K-theory

Comment: Any group with a non-trivial finite subgroup has infinite cohomological dimension over a ring where the order of that subgroup is not invertible.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg  Yes, I agree that $R$ being a (commutative?) PID means its contribution to the global dimension is relatively minor (like 0 or 1). However if $R=\mathbb Q$ then the  cohomological dimension of $G$ over $R$ and the global dimension of $RG$ can still be finite even if $G$ has non-trivial finite subgroups.

Comment: That is why I added that the order of the finite group should not be invertible.

Comment: In any event the cohomological dimension cannot be at most 1 unless the group acts on a tree with finite stabilizers with order invertible in R and that won't happen for non-virtually free arithmetic subgroups

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg OK, You make me suspect that my above comment is not helpful so I will probably delete it. Before I do, here is a simpler comment which is also a special case of the Question. Suppose that $G$ is a group of finite cohomological dimension $n$ over $\mathbb Z$: does this guarantee that $\textrm{gl.dim}(\mathbb ZG)=n+1$?

Comment: @PeterKropholler, that's a good question.

Comment: @PeterKropholler Please do not delete your (previous) comment.